# Is it a bad idea to daisy-chain Android Loaders?

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I need to get data from 2 sources online and would like to show progress of each as I do so. Once the data has been collected I can populate a listview.

My current implementation is that MyActivity implements LoaderCallbacks which in turn creates an instance of MyDataLoader (a class which extends AsyncTaskLoader). In the loadInBackground method of MyDataLoader it fetches the data from all sources and populates a Sqlite db. This db can then be used throughout.

The problem is that I am not giving the user any feedback as to where in the process we are.

So I was thinking of somehow daisy-chaining loaders using getLoaderManager().initLoader to create my loaders and then to iterate through the loaders in the loadermanager one at a time. As each loader finishes and returns to onLoadFinished I have an opportunity to set the text of a progressDialog to indicate the progress.

Is this a bad idea? Is there a simpler and better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible because `Loader`s load data in the background on separate threads... data is not loaded "sequentially" and thus showing progress in `onLoadFinished` won't give you an accurate picture of how much progress has actually been made.

All the user needs to know is that data is being loaded in the background. Even launching an entire dialog is a bit overkill and kind of disrupts the user experience in my opinion. Two alternatives off the top of my head are to:

1. Show an indeterminate progress icon in your layout or action bar.
2. Show a grayed-out `TextView` that says `Loading...` in the center of the layout. The `TextView` is finally hidden when the data has been retrieved from the web and is ready to be displayed on screen. Several Google-made apps choose this option, for example, Google Analytics.

Comment: Throbbers are always a handy way to do this but, if you know in advance you have to perform 2 loads, Showing a `0%`/`50%`/`100%` isn't neccesarily a bad idea. That said, there's no reason to load resources sequentially

Comment: @alex, will each loader call the onLoadFinished method separately once they finish or is there a single call? Or is there a final call made to another method once all the loaders have finished?

Comment: @CarllDev Loaders are totally independent from one another... the `LoaderManager` calls `onLoadFinished` each time a Loader has finished its load (note that this `Loader` will be passed as the first argument to the method too). The `LoaderManager` continuously starts/stops/resets/destroys the `Activity`'s Loaders across its entire lifecycle, so having a callback method that reports back when *all* of the Loaders are finished loading wouldn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @Basic Lets say our activity has 2 Loaders: `Loader A` and `Loader B`. The `Activity` is launched and 2 seconds later `Loader A` finishes its load. The activity shows then `50%` progress is complete. 5 milliseconds later, `Loader B` finishes its load. The activity then jumps from `50%` to `100%`. This is what I meant by it doesn't accurately illustrate the progress that has been made.

Comment: @AlexLockwood It depends on what the loader is doing and how long its likely to take - if each load is seconds only, 0/50/100 should be fine. If they're going to take tens of seconds, the ideal is to display something like `(A/TotalA + B/TotalB) /2` - This assumes you have a way of determining max source size _before_ the download. Perhaps you could raise events from within the loaders to notify the parent activity of progress?

Comment: Ok, so what if I only created the 2nd loader when the 1st calls onLoadFinished. I could then indicate which bit of data is being fetched when it happens. I would still use the indeterminate progress indicator. This is even more of a daisy chain, but could it work? Is it an anti pattern?

Comment: @CarllDev That would slow down your app by at most a factor of 2, since now the `Loader`s aren't executing simultaneously in the background.

Comment: @CarllDev if you care so much about showing progress, maybe you could simply combine the two `Loader`s into one?

Comment: @CarllDev unless you are expecting the web requests to take an unusually long time, the easy answer would be to show an indeterminate dialog/icon when you initialize the `Loader`s, and then hide it after *both* `Loader`s have called `onLoadFinished`.

Comment: @AlexLockwood The application takes around 20 seconds to do the retrieval of data from the online source. I didn't think that there would be a quicker way to do that retrieval, so I focussed on making the user aware of the fact that something is happening.
The better approach is to reduce the time (obviously), so I'll go with the dual loader approach and dismiss the progress dialog when both have finished.

Comment: @CarllDev 20 seconds is ridiculous, TBH... no one wants to wait that long. Is it possible to cache these results in a database so the user only has to wait one time (i.e. the first time the user starts the app?). The `Loader` could then load the data from the database and then there could be a background service adding data to the database in the background maybe? Yeah, 20 seconds is a very long time -_-

Comment: @AlexLockwood Yep, I'm calling the service with a version number, which checks whether the data it holds has a later version. It won't send any data back if the version is the same.
The 20 seconds load time is therefor only when the version changes or on first load.
This particular bit of code is a big headache for me, as I'm trying to avoid having to check the server database for all versions > the version passed in as this will take up time and resource on the server. So I simply cache the latest version with all data when the data changes, that way there is only one place to look for latest

Comment: @AlexLockwood The call to the service also only ever happens when the application starts, thereby helping to save some battery. I saw this big-cookie / small-cookie talk done by Reto Meier and thought it would be better than querying the data add-hoc. Funny enough, the ad-hoc queries are quicker, but battery will drain more that way. I guess its a trade off...